# How to control order of deployment (EJB first and then MBeans deployment) in Wildfly 8.2.0 AS

Tags: ejb-3.1, wildfly-8, jboss6.x, mbeans

I am migrating an EAR application containing MBeans from `JBoss 6 AS` to `Wildfly 8.2.0 AS`. In my EAR application, MBeans depend on EJB before initialization.

In `JBoss 6 AS`, `@DependsOn` annotation used in MBean maintained the sequence of the deployment i.e. Dependent EJB gets deployed and then, MBean gets deployed.

In `Wildfly 8.2.0`, I am trying to implement the same and `@DependsOn` is not working.

I tried the below in `jboss-service.xml` to have MBeans deployed only after the deployment of `EAR` file but this did not happen.

```
 <mbean code="sample.HelloWorldService" name="sample:service=HelloWorld,id=1">
    <depends>jboss.j2ee:service=EARDeployment,url='application.ear'</depends>
</mbean>
```

I also tried `@startup` in EJB but I cannot control the sequence i.e. 1. EJB deployment 2. MBeans deployment.

Can anyone please help about how to control the order of deployment in `Wildfly 8.2.0`. I need to deploy EJB first and then MBeans. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just a comment

About the EJB that you want to get from the MBeans, maybe you are misunderstanding the specificaction of [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile). It express an initialization dependency between **singleton components** (even if the related EJB are singleton be aware about possible problems with DependsOn like [WLFY-4251](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4251)).

### Workaround

Due to you are working with Jboss/Wildfly Server, you have the option to use the [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly#ClassLoadinginWildFly-JBossDeploymentStructureFile) for specify dependency between modules. 
Perhaps, as your are packing all in the same EAR application, you can separate the components into modules, let's say one *MBean.sar* module that contains the MBeans and other *RelatedEJBs.jar* module with the EJBs referenced by your MBeans.

Then you define the next dependency of *MBeans.sar* over *RelatedEJBs.jar*,

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   ...
   <sub-deployment name="RelatedEJBs.jar">
     ...
   </sub-deployment>
   <sub-deployment name="MBeans.sar">
     <dependencies>
       <!-- Adds a dependency on the ejb jar. This could also be done with a Class-Path entry -->
       <module name="deployment.YouApp.ear.RelatedEJBs.jar" />
     </dependencies>
   </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Edit: A useful [migration guide to Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly).

Comment: Many thanks for the response .. Guillermo. The concern I have is MBeans are scattered in different JAR and EJB maven sub-artifacts and currently, I have jboss-service.xml containing MBean definitions in META-INF of EAR. I am not aware whether I can create a single SAR file containing jboss-service.xml that relates to different MBeans in different JARs. I also tried <initializeInOrder>true</initializeInOrder> in EAR pom.xml but it order of deployment is not working. Could you please share if you have any suggestion on this.

Comment: I will add a link to a useful wildly migration guide. See the " Update Applications That Use Service-style Deployments " section to response your doubts

Comment: Today, I tried a created a separate sub module (sar) containing only jboss-servcie.xml and added within EAR as this module has access on other JARs including EJB jar. I added jboss-deployment-structure.xml as per your suggestion but it is not deploying in the sequence. I am adding this descriptor file under META-INF of EAR. Will this file not work only for sub-module deployments within a single deployment EAR ? Please share if you have any comments. Many thanks .. again.

Comment: I'm not aware about any bug releated with... Edit the question, include the descriptor file and the new structure/modules you made.

Comment: Many thanks for the help.. Guillermo. I could achieve this by adding a singleton startup local bean which takes care of registering MBeans programatically.

Comment: @sridhar so you use a \@PostConstruct method of that singleton? Because it is invoked after injection is done, resolving your dependency issue, right? Good!

Comment: yeah.. Guillermo. I am registering all the MBeans using singleton @PostConstruct. It worked! Many thanks for your help ;)